# Cannot POST /api/register in Node Js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am new at here and I am getting Can not post /api/register error in postman and 404 not found in console, I have checked all the possible question answers. Please assist me as soon as possible.
Thanks in advance.

The auth.controller.js file

```
var express = require ('express'); //EXPRESS Package
var route = express.Router();   //define our app using express
// var userModel = require('../model/user.model');
// var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');// get body-parser
route.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
route.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
/**
 * 
 * Register user
 */
route.post('/api/register', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);//res.sendStatus(200);
    // userModel.create(req.body).then( function () {

    //         res.sendStatus(200);
    // }).catch( function (err) {

    //     res.status(400).send(err);
    // });
});

/**
 * 
 * Login user
 */
route.post('/api/login', function (req, res) {

    // userModel.authenticate(req.body.email, req.body.password).then( function () {

    //     res.sendStatus(200);
    // }).catch( function (err) {

    //     res.status(400).send(err);
    // });
});
module.exports = route;
```

=========================================================================
The server.js File

```
var express = require ('express'); //EXPRESS Package
var app = express();    //define our app using express

var cors = require('cors');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');// get body-parser
// var morgan = require('morgan'); //use to see requests
// var assert = require('assert');
// var path = require('path');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// app.use(cors());

/**
 * Header Control
 */
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version');
  next();
} );
//routes
app.use('/api/register', require('./controllers/auth.controller'));
app.use('/api/login', require('./controllers/auth.controller'));
// app.use('/api/users', require('./controllers/users.controller'));

// app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
//     res.send('/api/login');
// } );
// start server
var server = app.listen(8001, 'localhost', function () {

    console.log('Server listening at http://' + server.address().address + ':' + server.address().port);
});

// module.exports = app;
```

Comment: `/api/register/api/register/` is the route you defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use

```
app.use('/api/register', require('./controllers/auth.controller'));
```

Your application routes everything that comes to `/api/register` into `require('./controllers/auth.controller')`. Then `require('./controllers/auth.controller')` checks the **remainder of the url** for `/api/register` or `/api/login`, routes the request to the respective middleware if your router gets a match.

In other words, you need to post to /api/register/api/register in order to reach your desired middleware.

For a quick solution:

You should delete

```
app.use('/api/register', require('./controllers/auth.controller'));
app.use('/api/login', require('./controllers/auth.controller'));
```

and replace it with:

```
app.use('/', require('./controllers/auth.controller'));
```

For a better one:

You should delete

```
app.use('/api/register', require('./controllers/auth.controller'));
app.use('/api/login', require('./controllers/auth.controller'));
```

and replace it with:

```
app.use('/api', require('./controllers/auth.controller'));
```

in your app.js and also in your `auth.controller.js`  you should replace:

```
route.post('/api/register', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);//res.sendStatus(200);
    // userModel.create(req.body).then( function () {

    //         res.sendStatus(200);
    // }).catch( function (err) {

    //     res.status(400).send(err);
    // });
});

/**
 * 
 * Login user
 */
route.post('/api/login', function (req, res) {

    // userModel.authenticate(req.body.email, req.body.password).then( function () {

    //     res.sendStatus(200);
    // }).catch( function (err) {

    //     res.status(400).send(err);
    // });
});
```

with:

```
route.post('/register', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);//res.sendStatus(200);
    // userModel.create(req.body).then( function () {

    //         res.sendStatus(200);
    // }).catch( function (err) {

    //     res.status(400).send(err);
    // });
});

/**
 * 
 * Login user
 */
route.post('/login', function (req, res) {

    // userModel.authenticate(req.body.email, req.body.password).then( function () {

    //     res.sendStatus(200);
    // }).catch( function (err) {

    //     res.status(400).send(err);
    // });
});
```

Comment: Great.. Thanks alot. I never thought about that. Amazing... but one more thing if I have more controllers for more dynamic pages then it will check all the times in auth.controller or it will directly find the target controller

Comment: Depends entirely on how your app uses your other controllers. It's too long to tell in a comment but here is a short summary: You have those functions that take req and res, right? They take one more parameter: next. If you have multiple controllers for a single route and you call "next();" at the end of the first controller, that way you can call the second controller. Otherwise you can't call the second controller.